# Sending an RSSI value as an advertising packet?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can I send an RSSI value as an advertising packet from a peripheral?  I don't want to have to connect to the central manager in order to read the RSSI value.  Can this be done?  Also I want the peripheral to be able to send these advertisements from an app that is running in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSSI comes free when you advertise any Bluetooth Low Energy device.. so yes it can/will display RSSI, and you don't have to do anything extra (as long as you've set up your peripheralManager to advertise properly).

Comment: RSSI value is part of the Bluetooth LE advertising packet, regardless of the device.